# How to access another elements on top layer in CSS hover?

Tags: html, css, hover

How to set `div_MenuDetail` display property for hide/visible, From `li_Menu_2` hover?

```css
    #li_Menu_2:hover (????????????) #div_MenuDetail {
        display:block;
    }
```

```html
    <ul>
      <li id='li_Menu_1'><a href='#'>Item 1</a></li>
      <li id='li_Menu_2'><a href='#'>Item 2</a></li>
      <li id='li_Menu_3'><a href='#'>Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id='div_MenuDetail' style='display:none;'>
      bla bla bla....
    </div>
```

Comment: Not possible, you can't traverse up with CSS (C stands for `cascade` ) You will have to change your HTML Structure.

Answer (score 0):

Just add '+' on the css like that...

`#li_Menu_2:hover + #div_MenuDetail {
    display:block;
}`

Comment: unfortunately not.
as I understand it, css doesn't allow you to check for items that are not below or at the same level.
li is under ul. div is at the level of ul. So you need to go back to ul from il and then go to ul level div.
thank you for your interest.

Comment: have you tried because mine is work the same level at your code !